# Visual Studio Code can’t run debugger on an iOS Device

Tags: debugging, ionic2, visual-studio-code

Below is my environment.

```
Node v7.6.0
Cordova –v 6.5.0
Ionic 2 – v 2.2.1
VS code – 1.10.1
```

Ever time I run the debugger in Visual Studio Code to Run iOS on device I get the following statement then the error.

Installing app on device
Launching app
Timeout launching application. Is the device locked?

Error message I see as well.

> [cordova-tools] Error processing "launch": {_stack}

I have built a new project from scratch and I receive the same error. I can’t debug on a ios Device with Visual Studio Code. The app does launch and I can run the app on the device but can’t use the debugger with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Teli